# При запуске проекта возникает ошибка warning: classpath entry points to a non-existent location

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, warning

Первый раз удалось её исправить, добавив строку `kapt.incremental.apt=false` в файл `gradle.properties,` но, после обновления Android Studio она вернулась, я обновил (и, возможно, добавил) все зависимости, которые Android Studio предлагала в разделе `Project Structure` -> `Suggestions`, ошибка исчезла. Сегодня запустил проект, она появилась снова.

Comment: Так ошибка Gradle или Android Studio? Больше деталей, логи приведите.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, судя по тому, что я прочитал об этой ошибке, проблема в gradle, в виду чего не особо понятно, где я должен прописывать логи

Comment: `gradle clean build` запустите в терминале проекта и там все логи будут.